# How can I make this center in the middle of the page?

Tags: jquery, html

I'm trying to center this div using JQuery so its responsive but I can't seem to do it I've tried this

```js
function resize() {
  var h = $(window).height();
  var w = $(window).width();
  var ct = $("#content");
  ct.height(h / 2.5);
  ct.width(w / 2.5);
  ct.css("left", w / 2);
  ct.css("right", w / 2);
  ct.css("top", h / 2);
  ct.css("bottom", h / 2);
}
resize();
$(window).on("resize", function() {
      resize();
    })
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style>
  #content {
    border: 1px black solid;
  }
</style>
<div id="content"></div>
```

it doesn't center at all I don't know how I can center and still be compatible with mobile

Comment: is there a reason youre not centering it with CSS??

Answer (score 1):

To center the `<div>`, you can use this code :

```css
#content {
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  border: 1px solid black;
  min-height: 20px;
  min-width: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div id="content"></div>
```

Without using any Javascript.

Answer (score 1):

Forget about centering items this way and just simply turn into flexbox

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

.wrapper .child {
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="child">
    hello
  </div>
</div>
```

It's safe to use: https://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox

Answer (score 1):

You can center elements ***without*** using any jQuery/JS at all, which is recommended.

```
#element {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;  /* aligns element's top edge to 50% from the top edge of the page */
  left: 50%; /* aligns element's left edge to 50% from the left edge of the page */
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%); /* values are relative to the element's width and height */
}
```

You do ***not*** need to set `right` and `bottom` if you set `top` and `left`. As you can see, the code below is sufficient.

```css
div {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  background: black;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

---

Notably, you can center elements within other elements using `absolute` if the parent is `position: relative`. For instance...

```css
#parent {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  position: relative;
  top: 25px;
  left: 75px;
  background: black;
}

#child {
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  background: lime;
}
```

```html
<div id='parent'>
  <div id='child'></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Depends what you mean by center. So many factors. You may want to do this on mobile.

```css
*{
  box-sizing:border-box; padding:0; margin:0;
}
html,body{
  width:100%; height:100%;
}
#test{
   width:100px; height:20px; margin-top:calc(50% - 10px); margin-left:calc(50% - 50px);
}
```

```html
<html xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml' xml:lang='en' lang='en'>
  <head>
    <meta charset='UTF-8' /><meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, height=device-height, initial-scale:1' />
    <title>Test Template</title>
    <link type='text/css' rel='stylesheet' href='external.css' />
    <script type='text/javascript' src='external.js'></script>
  </head>
<body>
  <div id='test'>test</div>
</body>
</html>
```

This design should work with test inside any other Element. Change the width and height accordingly with calc in mind.